# navigation bar is not navigating to about page

Tags: html

The navigation bar contains HOME,ABOUT,WORK,CONTACT. With the help href I could navigate through the page (single page website).

ISSUE :
Everything works except ABOUT

Tried:
Checked if there was any typo but none.
Other navs works fine, navigating to home,work and contact.

Thanks in advance :)

CODE:

```
<body>

    <div class="home-page">

      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">LOGO</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#home-page">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#about-page">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#myCarousel">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <h1 class="name-title">Kannan Vaidyanath</h1>
      <h3 class="work-title">Film Editor | Designer</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="about-page">
      <img class="picture-img" src="images/picture-circle.png" alt="profile-pic">
      <p class="about-me">My name is Kannan Vaidyanath. I was born and raised in India, growing up with a passionate interest for football and film editing
        With these interests combined, I created a Youtube channel in 2014 dedicated to football videos made with a cinematic flair.
        My channel currently has more than 8K subs with more than 1M views worldwide.
        In 2018 and 2019, I collaborated with FIFA to create content for FIFA Club World Cup and FIFA Women's World Cup.</p>
    </div>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/454281786" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" >The Liverpool Way</iframe>
        </div>
<!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
<footer id="footer">

      <i><a class="social-icon fab fa-facebook-f" href="https://facebook.com/KVPicturesOfficial"></a></i>
    </footer>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**href** (href="#about-page") specified by you defines only attribute **id**, and you forgot to set the it attribute for **about-page**. Do this:

```
<div id="about-page" class="about-page">
```

Comment: Works ! Thanks mate :)

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas, no problem :)